# ngModel value is coming as undefined when used with input

Tags: angular, input, angular-ngmodel

html:

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="timestamp">
    <button (click)="getInstantDetails()">display</button>
```

component.ts

```
  timestamp: any;
  getInstantDetails(): void {
    console.log(this.timestamp);
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [SchedulerService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I'm getting timestamp value as undefined. is there anything I'm missing here.?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as expected. You did not initialize `timestamp: any` to anything so its `undefined`.

Change `timestamp: string = 'hello';` and getInstantDetails() will log `'hello'`.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxe51w)